# Validating KB in system and Require only single output Powershell

Tags: powershell

Dont know why its giving multiple output result. My requirement is Check the KB installed or not if not installed then download and install only missing one otherwise show me Already installed.

```
$appArray = (
  @{
    App         = ($thisApp = 'kb5017024')
    App_source  = 'https://catalog.s.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2022/08/windows10.0-kb5017024-x64-ndp48_f2a8bd55b98a9cabc5a8b6179f619165b29c8273.msu'
    Destination = "c:\temp\$thisApp.msu"
    Argument    = '/S'
  },
  @{
    App         = ($thisApp = 'kb5012170')
    App_source  = 'https://catalog.s.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2022/08/windows10.0-kb5012170-x64_0558b5879de03bfb5319b1244d84ca3735a6a377.msu'
    Destination = "c:\temp\$thisApp.msu"
    Argument    = '/norestart /qn'
  }
)

foreach ($app in $appArray) {
  
  $installed = get-wmiobject win32_quickfixengineering -ComputerName $env:computername | Where-Object { $_.HotFixID -Match $app.App }
  $installed.HotFixID
  if ($installed.HotFixID -Match $app.App) {
    Write-Host "$($app.App) already installed."
  }
  else {
    if ((Test-Path $app.Destination) -eq $false) {
      New-Item -ItemType File -Path $app.Destination -Force
    }
    #install software
    Invoke-WebRequest $app.App_source -OutFile $app.Destination -PassThru
    Start-Process -FilePath $app.Destination -ArgumentList $app.Argument -Wait
    #Delete installer
    Remove-Item -Recurse $app.Destination
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rewrite of your code.
In your $appArray you had items like `($thisApp = 'kb5017024')`, but variable `$thisApp` is never defined.

Also, by filtering `Where-Object { $_.HotFixID -Match $app.App }` you are filtering away all updates you would like to install..

Try

```
$appArray = (
  @{
    Id          = 'kb5017024'
    App_source  = 'https://catalog.s.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2022/08/windows10.0-kb5017024-x64-ndp48_f2a8bd55b98a9cabc5a8b6179f619165b29c8273.msu'
    Destination = "c:\temp"
    Argument    = '/S'
  },
  @{
    Id          = 'kb5012170'
    App_source  = 'https://catalog.s.download.windowsupdate.com/d/msdownload/update/software/secu/2022/08/windows10.0-kb5012170-x64_0558b5879de03bfb5319b1244d84ca3735a6a377.msu'
    Destination = "c:\temp"
    Argument    = '/norestart /qn'
  }
)

$installed = (Get-HotFix).HotFixID  # or use (Get-WmiObject win32_quickfixengineering).HotFixID
foreach ($app in $appArray) {
    if ($installed -contains $app.Id) {
        Write-Host "$($app.Id) already installed." -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "Installing $($app.Id).."
        # create a folder for the updates
        $updateDir  = Join-Path -Path $app.Destination -ChildPath 'MyUpdates'
        $null = New-Item -Path $updateDir -ItemType Directory -Force 
        # create a full path and filename for the downloaded file
        $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $updateDir -ChildPath ('{0}.msu' -f $app.Id)
        try {
            #install software
            Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $app.App_source -OutFile $targetFile -ErrorAction Stop
            Start-Process -FilePath $targetFile -ArgumentList $app.Argument -Wait -ErrorAction Stop
            Write-Host "Installing $($app.Id) Done!" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        catch {
            Write-Warning "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
        # Delete the install folder and everything in it
        $updateDir | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
    }
}
```